# When will be the developer certifications for SharePoint 2013 available?

Tags: 2013, certification, developer

Currently i'm doing my exams for the MCSE here: http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx#fbid=EV6rgUyFq8c

My question is: **When will be the certifications ready for the developer track?**

Does anyone have some insider information? :D
I heard that they are expected at the end of April. Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Microsoft Certified Solutions Developer (MCSD) in SharePoint you will need to pass 4 exams. Two of them are SharePoint focused,  and two of them are from the MCSD: Web Application  part.

**SharePoint Focused**:

*70-488: Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions* - [Exam Objectives](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-488#fbid=Sb5t5j2IYqy)

*70-489: Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Advanced Solutions* - [Exam Objectives](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-489#fbid=Sb5t5j2IYqy)

**Web Focused:**

*70-480: Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3* - [Exam Objectives](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam-70-480.aspx#fbid=Sb5t5j2IYqy) (PS: You can take this exam for free at the moment. more info HERE) 
TBD

*70-486: Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications* - [Exam Objectives](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam-70-486.aspx#fbid=Sb5t5j2IYqy)

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/mcsd-windows-store-apps-certification.aspx#fbid=8DLJM9o9DXL

> The beta of the 70-488 and 70-489 exams should be available in the
>   first week of April  and run until the exams go "live" the first week
>   in July.

http://www.absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/02/three-new-facts-on-sharepoint-2013-mcsd.html