# Is there going to be a "MCSD: SharePoint" certificate?

Tags: certificate

Researching it for long now I found no clear answer and found controversial (but mostly old) info about this issue.

I know for a fact that MCPD has evolved to MCSD (Microsoft Certified Solutions Developer); the new certificates of MCSD are nicely listed at this page here: http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/mcsd-certification.aspx#fbid=fpR-o5C3m1R

However in the same previous page I can't see MCSD for SharePoint! This post at StackExchange ([When will the SharePoint 2013 exams be available](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41642/when-will-the-sharepoint-2013-exams-be-available)) mentions that this certificate is already set by Microsoft and it even mentions the requirements for this certificate but none of the info is found on Microsoft site (based on my researches though).

The site here: http://www.absolute-sharepoint.com/2012/12/sharepoint-2013-mcsd-developer.html
mentions roughly similar info as the previous one and it even gives an upgrade path from MCPD to MCSD (www.absolute-sharepoint.com/2012/12/sharepoint-2013-mcsd-developer.html)

However as in the first link I mentioned here, there seems to be no offcial "MCSD: SharePoint" (at least not yet)!

So what is the truth about MCSD: SharePoint? Is there going to be a "MCSE: SharePoint" certificate? Any requirements announced yet? Any upgrade path from MCPD to MCSE announced? What is the future of MCPD: SharePoint 2010?

Thanks for viewing and participating : )

Comment: MCPD: SharePoint 2010 is there and will stay for next 3 years based on SharePoint 2007 expire date. I am planning to do MCPD: SharePoint 2010 very soon and later on update it for SP 2013.

Comment: @hupseb did you even went through the links in that blog post, the information provided in that blog post is out-dated.

Comment: http://www.absolute-sharepoint.com is giving a lot of "leaks" which some of them proved valid and some not.. However based on this site I found this: The beta of the 70-488 and 70-489 exams should be available in the first week of April (2013) and will go "live" the first week in July. Apparently we should wait to see! Again the very first link I mentioned in my question seems to be place we should check to get the correct & official news.. I thought I could get some insider hints here : P Thanks for all your participations : )

Comment: @AMT, Blog is providing these links that are not working, http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-488
http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-489, I am not saying post is not useful but it got broken links...

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62983/when-will-be-the-developer-certifications-for-sharepoint-2013-available/62989#62989

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused with out-dated information,

If you want to do certification in SharePoint 2013 as expert then, here's the list of exams,

[image]

MCSD SharePoint not available yet as on Microsoft Certification site,

[image]

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx#fbid=MDgfOwqPuct) & [Source2](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/mcsm-sharepoint-certification.aspx#fbid=MDgfOwqPuct)

Comment: What is the URL of this page?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The mentioned exams are for SharePoint Administration. I am looking for SharePoint Development Exams. Thanks again!

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I checked, these are still Administrative exams. Look at Audience Profile of 331, it says this:

Candidates for this exam typically have more than four years of hands-on experience planning and maintaining SharePoint and other core technologies upon which SharePoint depends, including Windows Server 2008 R2 or later, Internet Information Services (IIS), Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 or later, Active Directory, and networking infrastructure services. I am looking for "MCSD" not anything else! Thanks again : )

Comment: Sorry, I miss-understood, I don't think it's available yet.

Comment: Correct at the time of writing. The SharePoint 2013 development exams (70-488 and 70-489) are still not publicly available as of 8 July 2013.

Answer (score 1):

These two exans are out since June 20:

- [Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?id=70-488#fbid=SECJLpNfMkr)
- [Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Advanced Solutions](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?id=70-489#fbid=SECJLpNfMkr)

They are most likely to be part of a future MCSD SharePoint 2013 certificate. They are together with 70-331 and 70-332 part of nine certificates in MCSM (Solution Master) SharePoint 2013. MCSM is the next step from MCSE, and most probably the same next step from MCSD.

However, no official sources have confirmed a MCSD SharePoint 2013 Certificate yet.

Comment: I don't think they are quite there yet. If you actually try to book a test they are missing from the Prometric site.

Comment: @SPDoctor LOL! That's some really bad usability there. You link to Prometric letting the user believe that she can take an exam. After ten steps (no kidding), the exam isn't available yet. Not surprising when it comes to MS, but still, that's bad. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I take that back, I must have skipped over them. They are available on the Prometric site as a selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion of recent information on the 2013 certifications, including the MCSD: http://www.excessivelyproductive.com/sharepoint-2013-certifications-1.aspx